# How can i "eliminate" a object name from a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to get is the following thing.
Starting from a json like this:

```
{
    "de": {
        "errors.de.i18n.js": {
            "errors": {
                "addcreditcard": "Wir konnten diese Karte nicht verifizieren. Bitte Ã¼berprÃ¼fe deine Angaben und    versuche es noch einmal."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would delete the second element of that json, in this case errors.de.i18n.js and get a json like this:

```
{
    "de": {
        "errors": {
            "addcreditcard": "Wir konnten diese Karte nicht verifizieren. Bitte Ã¼berprÃ¼fe deine Angaben und    versuche es noch einmal."
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you all

Comment: You should write some codes and share

Comment: What you want is not clear. Please elaborate more.

Comment: Also, this neither a valid JSON string nor a valid JS object.

Comment: Ok now is more clear, sorry

Comment: @somethinghere - It's not? Why not?

Comment: Well, it wasn't at the time I commented that (missing colons etc..) and people are confusing JSON with simple Javascript objects _way too much_. JSON is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the value you want to keep to to a new property in the object, then unset the one you want to delete.

```js
var object = {
  "de": {
    "errors.de.i18n.js": {
      "errors": {
        "addcreditcard": "Wir konnten diese Karte nicht verifizieren. Bitte Ã¼berprÃ¼fe deine Angaben und    versuche es noch einmal."
      }
    }
  }
};

object.de.errors = object.de['errors.de.i18n.js'].errors;
delete object.de['errors.de.i18n.js'];

console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
```

If there can be more properties in the sub-object, you can use a loop to copy all of them to the parent object.

```
var subobject = object.de['errors.de.i18n.js'];
for (var prop in subobject) {
    if (subobject.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        object.de[prop] = subobject[prop];
    }
}
delete object.de['errors.de.i18n.js'];
```

Comment: Excuse me but it does not work , you can give an example?

Comment: Oops, `unset` should have been `delete`. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new object and assign it what you need like this:

```
      var oldobj = { "de": { "errors.de.i18n.js": { "errors": { "addcreditcard":"Wir konnten diese Karte nicht verifizieren. Bitte Ã¼berprÃ¼fe deine Angaben und    versuche es noch einmal."}}}};
      var newobj = {'de': {'errors': []} };
      newobj.de.errors = oldobj.de['errors.de.i18n.js']['errors'];

      alert(JSON.stringify(newobj));
```

See my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fictus/eg5kkrmq/